# Get td value from specific tr (with mouse hover)

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

My problem is js sortable table that I also using mouse hover for it.
The problem is when I resort my table the hover url is not updating and I looking for how I can get for specific tr I selected the value of first td.

I tried with different variations such as:

```
$this.find('td:eq(0)')
```

or with

```
getElementById("trselect")
```

nothing works.

I use it with both mouse hover and probably looking for something like:

```
document.location.href = "details/" + $('tr').find('td:first-child').text();
```

Comment: we need more information. do you have any html to share?

Comment: This question is not answerable, you need to explain what you mean.

Comment: the td tag doesn't have a value attribute.. you mean innerHTML?

Comment: @reikyoushin Either `innerHTML` or `textContent`. It's a very poorly explained question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Pure JavaScript Solution

There are a bunch of jQuery answers but no jQuery tag so I'm offering a pure JavaScript solution for you. Installing a large library for this simple task seems pointless.

You can assign the row to a Javascript variable like this, and look for mouseover.

To get the first TD's content, you can use a function like this:

```
function getFirstTdContent(row) {
    elem = row.children[0];
    alert(elem.textContent); // Do whatever you want to do with the content here
}
```

To call it, declare your row like this:

```
<tr onmouseover='getFirstTdContent(this);'>
    <td>This should be returned</td>
    <td>This should not be returned</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this with jQuery:

Add jQuery library:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

Add jQuery code to get value of first TD:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('tr').mouseover(function(){
        var valueOfTd = $(this).find('td:first-child').text();
        alert(valueOfTd); // Do here what you want with the value.
        document.location.href = 'http://www.google.com/'+ valueOfTd;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You should use `td:first-child` selector to be more explicit. Also he probably wants to deal with `.text()` rather than `.html()`.

Comment: yes, this one looks good and almost what i need, trying to figure out, but actually what i need is to get td value for change location/href. currently i have document.location.href =   "details/" + tdvalue; but it still doesn't pass the value from your function to mine :\

Comment: @Joao Paulo , i need something like:   document.location.href =   "details/" + $('tr').find('td:first-child').text();

Comment: @Joao Paulo , yes, i tested it also and it works for me too, just doing not exactly what i need) i need to redirect the page with href to the link that includes the first td value

Comment: If your document.location.href is in other function you need to pass variable as parameter to the function. Show all your js code and I'll try to help you more.

Comment: Is redirecting without the value?

Comment: ok, i figured out, it works correct. almost.. but i will found what it left to do.. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using jQuery...

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/cF63Q/

```
$(function(){
    $('#myTable tr').hover(function(){
       console.log($(this).find('td').first().html());
    });
});
```