# Call Function on Tabel Row Hover

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

I want to call a function that prints the contents of a row every time I hover over it in a table. So far I have this:

```js
function tablemouseover(event) {
  console.log(event.target);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr onmouseover='tablemouseover(event)'>
    <td>times[row]</td>
    <td>locations[row][0]</td>
    <td>locations[row][1]</td>
    <td>AllDistances[row]m</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However this just gets me `<td>` I am hovered over.

Comment: Sounds like a good use of the `useCapture` argument to `addEventListener`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get td value from specific tr (with mouse hover)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957321/get-td-value-from-specific-tr-with-mouse-hover)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the text of the cell by calling `textContent`. If you want the col/row indices, you can get them by grabbing the positional index of the element within it's row or table (body).

```js
const getChildIndex = node => 
  Array.prototype.indexOf.call(node.parentNode.children, node);

function tablemouseover(event) {
  const
    row = event.currentTarget,
    col = event.target,
    rowIndex = getChildIndex(row),
    colIndex = getChildIndex(col),
    allText = [...row.children].map(td => td.textContent);
  
  console.log(`Cell (${colIndex}, ${rowIndex}): ${event.target.textContent}`);
  console.log(`Row [${rowIndex}]: ${JSON.stringify(allText)}`);
}
```

```css
table, th, td { border: thin solid grey; }
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
th, td { padding: 0.5em; }

.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 5.25em !important; }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr onmouseover='tablemouseover(event)'>
      <td>times[row]</td>
      <td>locations[row][0]</td>
      <td>locations[row][1]</td>
      <td>AllDistances[row]m</td>
    </tr>
    <tr onmouseover='tablemouseover(event)'>
      <td>times[row]</td>
      <td>locations[row][0]</td>
      <td>locations[row][1]</td>
      <td>AllDistances[row]m</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `closest('tr')` to search up the DOM tree for the closest `tr` parent and then log its `innerHTML` like so:

```js
function tablemouseover(event){
   console.log(event.target.closest('tr').innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr onmouseover='tablemouseover(event)'>
<td>times[row]</td>
<td>locations[row][0]</td>
<td>locations[row][1]</td>
<td>AllDistances[row]m</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `onmouseenter` not `onmouseover`

[Read what different between](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseenter_event)

```js
function tablemouseover(event){
       console.log(event.target.innerHTML);
    }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr onmouseenter ='tablemouseover(event)'>
    <td>times[row]</td>
    <td>locations[row][0]</td>
    <td>locations[row][1]</td>
    <td>AllDistances[row]m</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```